# Youtube iframe embed looping working in every browser except IE9 & IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, youtube

Here's my HTML...

```
<iframe width="1425" height="613" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IHJ-djBr0Q0?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;playlist=IHJ-djBr0Q0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This autoplays and loops fine on every browser except IE9/10. It works in IE8 cuz it uses the flash player. I'm not sure why IE11 works and 9/10 don't though. Ideas?

Note: it DOES work if you have flash installed i believe, but I would prefer they use the HTML5 player.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and after extensive testing and Googling, I couldn't find a reason.  I then tried a number of ways to get it to work, and I found that removing and reinserting the iframe into the DOM (and also re-registering the Player) worked.

Here's a codepen for it http://codepen.io/toddzebert/pen/XbYjdq

Note the `var console = function` at the top is only to provide IE9/10 commentary since those browsers don't like console.log in iframes (such as codepen's).